# Python enable FastAPI API Key header

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi

I want to enable API Key header to generate a Bearer token in my API using FastAPI, but I'm having troubles getting and sending Bearer token from the OpenAPI UI, my token endpoint looks like this

```
api_key_header = APIKeyHeader(name='X-API-Key', auto_error=True)

app_auth = APIRouter()


@app_auth.post('/token', summary="Returns Bearer Token",
               tags=["Auth"])
async def login(api_key_header: str = Security(api_key_header)):
    if api_key_header != '123':
        raise HTTPException(status_code=HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
                            detail='wrong api key',
                            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"})
    else:
        jwt_token = create_jwt_token(user)
        return jwt_token
```

This works and returns the bearer token as expected
[image]

It also shows me the header from the Authorize buttom
[image]
[image]

But then I have troubles by passing this generated token to another endpoint through OpenAPI (it works if I just send it in headers with other client), when I test other endpoint, its not sending the token in headers
[image]

I also have enabled

```
oauth_schema = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl='/token')
```

```
app = FastAPI(title="My test api", version="1.0")

app.include_router(app_auth)
app.include_router(app_test, prefix='/v1.0', dependencies=[Depends(check_jwt_token)])
```

and check_jwt_token

```
async def check_jwt_token(token: str = Depends(oauth_schema)):
   """
   it decods the token and check if already expired
   """
```

**extra:** you can see the endpoint handles correctly the Bearer token, testing from postman

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I just figure it out, here is the answer in case it helps someone else

I just had to change the `oauth_schema = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl='/token')`

for `oauth_schema = HTTPBearer()` and change
`async def check_jwt_token(token: HTTPAuthorizationCredentials = Security(oauth_schema))` , and inside the function:

`token= token.dict()['credentials']`